# Save AJAX response for other functions (e.g. global variable?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to PHP, JavaScript, JQuery, JSON and AJAX. I started a few weeks ago with learning all this stuff.
My Problem:
I'm creating a website which displays data from a database. On the website it should be possible to search, order and filter the data. 
For now I receive from an AJAX request a JSON_encoded array with all the data from the database. Now I'm asking whether it's possible to save the response from the AJAX request in a global variable for example so I don't need to get the data from the database again, if the user wants to order the data. (By using something like the php function "multisort()")
Or do I have to make a new query/Ajax request to order the data using in the query ORDER BY?

I've read already, that saving to a global variable doesn't work because of the     a asynchronicity of Ajax. So how is it possible to avoid many Ajax requests? or are many Ajax requests the usual solution to this problem?

I hope you're understanding my Problem.
If you want I can attach my written code, but there's no try to solve this problem, cause I want to understand what's the common solution.

Comment: Global variables do work as long as you access the data after it has be written to the variable...

Comment: If you're talking about data you want to be available for a specific user as she continues requesting pages you want to store the json data in [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Tecnically it's possible to save the data to a global var, or even to a hidden input. I don't recommend it though... Once you do a refresh on your browser you lose all your work. Besides, it's actually much faster to retry sorted records from the DB, than to do the sorting with javascript on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think its easier and much more efficient to do it from the Database. There you have SQL to help you with the filtering and sorting. Storing it in a variable could possibly use up too much memory on the server - just to store data which is already in the Database

For each request by the user, send a request to the Database and display the data

Comment: This is another (and the original ^) option.  It is also probably the most common option.  The database will optimize the queries (sorting/filtering/limiting) the fastest, though it does require making another AJAX call each time

Comment: making another ajax call is cheap in my view - when compared to the days when would have to reload the page. At least you're getting up-to-date data

Comment: I agree.  In most cases, this is the way to go

Comment: Thanks for the fast help. I think i'm going to make every time a new request then. Doing it this way means i don't need the send the ajax response JSON_encoded, right? Are there any advantages to respond with JSON (create the html data on the client-side) or ist it better to create the html data on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a user system in place, you can serialize or json_encode the data to the users session. Depends on the data to be honest though.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol.  There are a couple ways you can do this:

Store the data on the server.  You can use some kind of session mechanism and employ cookies so the server can keep track of user sessions.  In PHP, you would then be storing the data in the $_SESSION variable.

Store the data on the users machine.  Send it all over on the initial request and filter as necessary using javascript.

I would recommend the first option depending on how much data you're dealing with.  Sending large amounts can impede the performance of certain browsers.  Granted, if you're not implementing sessions already, now you will have to do that.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save your ajax response on client side in a global variable like this..  Hope this help.

```
if (!window.OPT) window.OPT = {};

$.ajax({ url: '/yourURL/' }).done( 
      function(data) {
    OPT.AJAXResult = data ;
        } );
```